# How do I grant characters the Light and Dark elements?

Tags: tactics-ogre-reborn

I'm playing Tactics Ogre for the first time via the remake Tactics Ogre: Reborn. I'm not very far into the game at all, and I'm confused about how to assign the Light and Dark elements to a character.

For the 6 "regular" elements I can just assign them when I create a character, but the Light and Dark elements aren't available. Based on some reading online I can tell it's possible to have characters with those elements, but I can't find any information on *how* to assign characters the Light and Dark elements.

**How do I assign characters the Light and Dark elements?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a units element by using an **elemental charm.** These are consumable items that will change a units element based on the charm type, and using a Light Charm or a Dark Charm will convert a units element to Light and Dark respectively.

Charms can be earned as rewards for completing bonus objectives. I assume they can also be  purchased from shops, but if so, I haven't gotten far enough into the game to do so.